# Problema con Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje y estoy haciendo una calculadora para empezar. La calculadora debe tener un pequeño sistema que simule una memoria donde se guardan los números. 
Por ejemplo, si escribo 56 y le doy en el botón de suma, el número 56 deberá guardarse en un array y si escribo luego 10 o dejo el 56 otra vez, ese número deberá anidarse al array también. 
Los números se guardan muy bien, pero cuando uso Array.Clear(numeros, 0, numeros.Length) no parece hacer nada y el programa continúa normalmente. 
¿Por qué no es tan sencillo vaciar un array con C#? Con Visual Basic.NET eso era fácil. Aquí es completamente diferente.

Comment: Hola Máxima, bienvenida a SOes, te gustaría compartir el código que has hecho para que todos los que andamos por estos lares de la red te demos una mano? Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es vaciar un array, puedes hacerlo asi

```
 int[] x = new int[10];
Array.Clear(x, 0, x.Length);

//  Sets a range of elements in an array to the default value of each element type.
```

Pero ten en cuenta que es un array, no se vacia... se iguala al valor por defecto del array (en este caso es 0), ya que el array tiene una dimensión fija.

si lo que quieres es vaciar, y modificar dicha dimensión te aconsejo que uses una lista

```
List<int> lista=new List<int>();
```

y para vaciarla

```
lista.Clear();
```

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no funciona :(

Comment: Algo mal tienes que estar haciendo, por que eso, te aseguro que funciona :), pon más código que podamos ver